# awesome wm taglist size

Tags: lua, config, awesome-wm, taglist

Can't find any manual about changing width of taglist element size.
Taglist element is wider than icons I had set. It looks really awful =(

Screenshot: http://s12.postimg.org/fkva7xywd/Screenshot_16_02_2014_16_04_07.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taglist element consist of icon, text and gap between them. This gap defined in awful.widget.common.list_update function in line

```
m = wibox.layout.margin(tb, 4, 4)
```

Despite you have no text, double gap is still here. To solve this problem you can copy list_update function to your rc file, fix it and send as fifth(!) argument in awful.widget.taglist.

Answer (score 1):

just tell your imagebox not to be resizable, example:

```
wibox.widget.imagebox(beautiful.clock, false)
```

or you can even resize you wibox:

```
mywibox[s] = awful.wibox({ position = "top", screen = s, height = 32 })
```

you just need to modify height value

or another method using wibox.layout.constraint:

```
clock_icon = wibox.widget.imagebox(beautiful.clock, true)
local const = wibox.layout.constraint()                  
const:set_widget(clock_icon)                             
const:set_strategy("exact")                              
const:set_height(16)
```

then, instead of adding your icon to the layout, just add the constraint.

Comment: You didn't understand the question, it's not widgets, it is layoutbox icons. And I need to change width, not height.